# Cannot access GIT remote with PhpStorm and WSL and Private Key

Tags: git, phpstorm, wsl-2

When trying to clone a remote repository in PhpStorm on Windows into WSL2 subsystem (`\\\$wsl\somedir\`) over SSH (`git@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git`) I get an error „Permission denied (public key)“. Private key is correctly located within `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`.

But when trying the same from a shell within WSL directly (after a `eval ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`) that works. But it is not possible using the PhpStorm GUI (`New Project -> Get from VCS`).

Comment: PhpStorm needs your private key configured for the windows side ([SSH settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/create-ssh-configurations.html)). PhpStorm's WSL integration is not yet as well integrated as VSCode's is.

Comment: In another machine (older PhpStorm version) it works fine without any additional SSH configuration. It is only about git, there are no ssh connections at all.

Comment: `git@someurl/repo.git` *is* an SSH connection

Comment: Yes, but I mean there is no concrete connection defined in „ssh settings“ on the other machine where it works.

Comment: Well well, the old *works on my machine* argument.. that's pretty difficult for us to guess the cause of. I would just configure the SSH settings and see if that works.

Comment: After „chmod 0600 id_rsa“ it works fine! IDE uses the key stored in WSL. But what I wonder about: even after a reboot of the host (windows) git connectivity works without asking for the keys passphrase. How is this possible? On the older machine I am prompted for it at least after a reboot, when accessing the git remote.

Comment: Must the key be located in `id_rsa` file specifically, or whatever ssh-agent is configured with will do?

Answer (score 0):

> Private key is correctly located within `/home/user/id_rsa`.

The default localtion should be `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`, not `/home/user/id_rsa`.

If that was a typo, and the key is actually in `.ssh`, open PhpStorm from a shell where you type first: `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'`.

Check [the terminal](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/terminal-emulator.html) (or try and clone from the terminal) to see what Git is trying to access as private key.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I will try your hint.

Answer (score 0):

Solution simply seems to be changing access rights for the private key stored in WSL with „chmod 0600 id_rsa“.

Comment: Mine are already like that.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-333903/WSL-bin-bash-line-1-warning-setlocale-LCALL-cannot-change-locale-enUS.UTF-8-No-such-file-or-directory-on-cloning-repo#focus=Comments-27-8272771.0-0) is what worked for me. Align your `~/.ssh/config` with the following:

```
Host github.com
        User git
        Hostname github.com
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
        StrictHostKeyChecking no
        IdentitiesOnly yes
        AddKeysToAgent yes
```

I suspect that PHPStorm uses some different kind of shell with different initial configuration, rather than the regular shell. The above instructs SSH to use a specific user with a specific key file (note that it can be named whatever you want, as long as you configure it this way, not just `id_rsa` etc), and no other way.